Can I fix browser apps that deprioritize code running off screen on inactive space on macOS?
I left Chrome browser working on a task in one space and go to another.  When I  come back I see that Chrome task that were not visible made less progress than it would done if I stay in that space.
This is 100% existing issue and not a seem, I've measured with stopwatch the time and the done progress being in app's space and off. Also, other browsers (Opera, Brave, Edge, any) behave the same.
I want browsers run with the same performance in the background.
macOS Sonoma 14.5. MacBook Air M2.
Is this possible for any browser?

What site did you use to measure performance?

Thanks for the edit! What is being asked of you is what specific workload are you running in the browser? Most people appreciate energy savings for off screen browsers. That way the battery and CPu is free for visible tasks in the foreground with priority. Basically what’s the problem here?
